# Wilson's Theorem Application to Quadratic Residues

Tags: proof-explanation, factorial, quadratic-residues

Im a noob and trying to prove: $(m!)^2\equiv(-1)^{m+1}\textrm{(mod p)}$ using Wilson's Theorem. Although it's on Wikipedia, I want to really understand what is happening. Could someone explain how $$\begin{align*}1*2\dotsb*(p-1)=1*(p-1)*2*(p-2)\dotsb m*(p-m)\end{align*}$$
What is m? How is it possible for (p-1)! to have this expansion. Then could someone also explain the property that was used to transform this: $$(-1)^m(m!)^2\equiv-1\textrm{(mod p)}$$ into $$(m!)^2\equiv(-1)^{m+1}\textrm{(mod p)}$$ I understand that $-1^1*-1^m=-1^{m+1}$, but how did the $-1^m$ move from the left side to the right. Thanks for help! [Wilson's Theorem Quadratic Residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m$ is $(p-1)/2$.

You can multiply a congruence by the same thing on both sides.  Also, $(-1)^m\cdot(-1)^m=(-1)^{2m}=1$.  Thus the result.